# Unrecognized font family 'Lato-Regular'

Tags: react-native

I started getting this error when building my project. "Unrecognized font family 'Lato-Regular' " I'm not sure how to fix it because "Lato-Regular" Is not a font I use in my project at all.. I even did a search in for my entire project that this font is not used or mentioned anywhere. I cleaned my build folder and tried adding it to my info file to see if this would fix the issue. It been a few days now of trying to fix this. This started after I made a change in my podfile. Specifically this:

```
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources"
        target.remove_from_project
```

My project won't archive without it. so removing it is not an option.

Here is my info.plist

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Kufam-SemiBoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Lato-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Lato-BoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Lato-Italic.ttf</string>
        <string>Lato-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: `<string>Lato-Regular.ttf</string>` So you _do_  use it.

Comment: I added this to see if it would remove the error.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by adding lato-regular.tff to my target. This might have to do with a recent module Awesome fonts that I installed.. I have to dig further but for now this was the solution.